# how to set/change SCSI controller type for a virtual machine using vmware sdk in c#

Tags: c#, vmware, scsi

I am trying to change SCSI Controller type of a virtual machine during creation process. I can use

VirtualLsiLogicSASController.sharedBus = VirtualSCSISharing.noSharing;

for setting it to no sharing option. But not able to change the Controller type. It is always "LSI Logic SAS". I want to set it to "LSI Logic Parallel".
I have tried to set the description attributes of SCSI Controller by using

```
 scsiCtrl.deviceInfo=new Description();
 scsiCtrl.deviceInfo.label =  "SCSI controller 0";
 scsiCtrl.deviceInfo.summary = "LSI Logic";
```

but it is not working. 
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution...
we have to use desired controller type.. i.e.

```
if scsiType == "sas":
        scsiCtrl = VirtualLsiLogicSASController()
    elif scsiType == "parallel":
        scsiCtrl = VirtualLsiLogicController()
    elif scsiType == "buslogic":
        scsiCtrl = VirtualBusLogicController()
    elif scsiType == "paravirt":
        scsiCtrl = ParaVirtualSCSIController()
```

It will set the SCSI Controller type to required type... 
thanks...